# InvalidOperationException: No method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied arguments

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

(Code below has been updated and worked properly)

There is dynamic OrderBy sample from LinqPad. What I want to do is just simply apply 'Where' rather than 'OrderBy' for this sample. Here is my code:

```
    IQueryable query =            
    from p in Purchases
    //where p.Price > 100
    select p;

string propToWhere = "Price"; 

ParameterExpression purchaseParam = Expression.Parameter (typeof (Purchase), "p");
MemberExpression member = Expression.PropertyOrField (purchaseParam, propToWhere);

Expression<Func<Purchase, bool>> lambda = p => p.Price < 100;
lambda.ToString().Dump ("lambda.ToString");


//Type[] exprArgTypes = { query.ElementType, lambda.Body.Type };
Type[] exprArgTypes = { query.ElementType };

MethodCallExpression methodCall =
    Expression.Call (typeof (Queryable), "Where", exprArgTypes, query.Expression, lambda);

IQueryable q = query.Provider.CreateQuery (methodCall);
q.Dump();
q.Expression.ToString().Dump("q.Expression");
```

This code gets exception:
"InvalidOperationException: No method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied arguments."

Any help is appraicated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the lambda that Jon Skeet supplied. Perhaps he can also explain why `ParameterExpression` is so painful to use and requires using the **same** instance, instead of being able to be matched by name :)
2. Modify this line:

```
Type[] exprArgTypes = { query.ElementType };
```

`exprArgTypes` is type parameters to

```
IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate).
```

As you can see it only has one type parameter - `TSource`, which is `Purchase`. What you were doing, effectively, was calling `Where` method with two type parameters like below:

```
IQueryable<Purchase> Where<Purchase, bool>(this IQueryable<Purchase> source, Expression<Func<Purchase, bool>> predicate)
```

Once both of those fixes are in the expression runs with no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your lambda expression creation looks odd to me. You're adding another parameter for no obvious reason. You're also using `Predicate<Purchase>` instead of `Func<Purchase, bool>`. Try this:

```
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Purchase, bool>>(
                    Expression.GreaterThan(member, Expression.Constant(100)), 
                    purchaseParam);
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your reply. The expression you provide complains
"The binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for the types 'System.Decimal' and 'System.Int32'."

Comment: Ah. You hadn't made it clear that `Price` is a decimal. The simplest solution is to change the 100 to 100m, I suspect.